# SingleProducerConstrained and MaxDegreeOfParallelism

Tags: c#, multithreading, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

In the C# TPL Dataflow library, SingleProducerConstrained is an optimisation option for ActionBlocks you can use when only a single thread is feeding the action block:

> If a block is only ever going to be used by a single producer at a
>   time, meaning only one thread at a time will be using methods like
>   Post, OfferMessage, and Complete on the block, this property may be
>   set to true to inform the block that it need not apply extra
>   synchronization.

What if an ActionBlock is fed using a single TransformBlock which have MaxDegreeOfPArallelism > 1 - would that violate the rules for setting SingleProcerContrained to true on the ActionBlock? or is a single TransformBlock with MaxDegreeOfPArallelism > 1 still counted as a "single producer"?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, I think it's considered a single producer.

This is because all the built-int blocks maintain ordering, so item 2 can be offered (using [the `OfferMessage()` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh160309)) to the target block only after item 1 has been accepted. And this constraint means that there can be only one thread offering messages to the target at a time, which follows the definition of "single producer".

Comment: What if EnsureOrdered is false?