# Is the TPL Dataflow SingleProducerConstrained referring to number of source block or the parallelism degree of them?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

Is the TPL Dataflow [`SingleProducerConstrained`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.singleproducerconstrained.aspx) option referring to the number of source blocks or the minimum total parallelism degree of the source blocks?

i.e. if I only have one source block linking to a block with this option, must the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of the source be 1 or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it means that (from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.singleproducerconstrained.aspx)):

> methods like `Post`, `Complete`, `Fault`, and `OfferMessage` will never be called concurrently.

So you should set this property to `true` (`false` is the default value) if you're 100%-sure that the block will get messages in it from **only one** source at **a given moment**. Examples:

- Block is target for only one linked source
- You use `lock` around all the method sending something to the block
- your app is single-threaded, and you sending messages not using the thread-pool or some other threading techniques.
- etc.

Now back to your question:

> if I only have one source block linking to a block with this option, must the `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of the source be 1 or not?

It should be `1`, as if it will be more than that, it can ruin some checks which are dropped with `SingleProducerConstrained` set to `true`.

Comment: This seems to contradict this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474082/singleproducerconstrained-and-maxdegreeofparallelism Are you sure about this?

Comment: @Magnus I cannot see any contradictions. As this is an accepted answer, it probably better to ask the OP, did this answer helped him or not

Comment: The answer by @svick in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22474082/singleproducerconstrained-and-maxdegreeofparallelism says that a source block with MaxDegreeOfParallelism > 1 is considerer a single producer, and if I understand your answer correctly you say it is not and that the target blocks need to have SingleProducerConstrained set to false. I just wanted to know how you came to this conclusion as the documentation seems to be a little bit fuzzy about this and other seems to say the opposite. Did you read it somewhere, did you test it, or other?

Comment: @Magnus Maybe I tried some example and/or read the code on reference code base. Unfortunately, can’t say for sure right now. Maybe JSteward may help.